# Java write byte in file

Tags: java

I am doing in Java a File Comprimir to a Binary File. The problem is the next, how can I write a Byte in a new File that the total size only occups 1 byte? I am doing the next:

```
FileOutputStream saveFile=new FileOutputStream("SaveObj3.sav");
        // Create an ObjectOutputStream to put objects into save file.
        ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);

        save.writeByte(0);


        save.close();
        saveFile.close();
```

That, only must to write a only byte in the file, but when I look the size,it occups 7 bytes. Anyone knows how can I write a only byte? Is there another way better?

Comment: What platform? How do you know it occupies 7 bytes?

Comment: I would say that probably ObjectOutputStream inserts additional informations regarding type of data (which is useful in serialization and deserialization). How does your program acts when you use `saveFile.write(0);` instead of `save.writeByte(0);`?

Comment: +1 to @Pshemo (who should make that an answer). The javadoc of the ObjectOutputStream constructor says:  *This constructor writes the serialization stream header to the underlying stream*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `ObjectOutputStream`. Use the `FileOutputStream` directly:

```
FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("SaveObj3.sav");
out.write(0);
out.close();
```

Comment: That will actually write an `int`, i.e. four bytes, because the [FileOutputStream.write(int b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int)) method will be invoked. To write a single `byte`, one can use the [FileOutputStream.write(byte[] b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(byte[])) by wrapping the `0` in a `byte[]`, e.g. `out.write(new byte[]{0});`

Comment: @matsev: Funny: Then why tell the doc you linked: "Writes the specified _byte_ to this file..."? And why does running the code only writes _one_ bye? Oh, and the doc for `OutputStream#write(int)` tells you: "The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b  are ignored."

Comment: @Runemoro: Your first version was correct also and more mininal.

Comment: @A.H. Ok... I made it `write(0)` again.

Comment: @A.H. Interesting, I guess I did not read the JavaDocs thoroughly. It makes you wonder why they did not make the signature `FileOutputStream.write(byte b)` in the first place...

Comment: @matsev: Because `byte` and `short` arithmetic is done as `int` anyway. And because writing `out.write(42);` would not be possible - you would have to use `out.write((byte)42);`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Now I can write too a byte[] to do the compressor^^. Thanks!

Comment: @A.H. True, but what bothers me is that people (like myself) would make the assumption that `out.write(100000)` is valid if they just uses tab-completion in their IDEs without reading the JavaDocs.

Comment: @matsev That's why RTFM is always a good idea ;-) The complete `InputStream` and `OutputStream` hierarchy is all about reading and writing bytes. Everything else is just deco. So when writing anything into a byte sink you always have to think how to encode/decode the non-byte stuff. Either by using one of the appropriate deco methods or by doing it by hand. Your large integer is just an example for that.

Answer (score 3):

As JB Nizet noticed documentation of [ObjectOutputStream constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream%29) states that this object also

> writes the serialization stream header to the underlying stream

which explains additional bytes.

To prevent this behaviour you can just use other streams like `FileOutputStream` or maybe `DataOutputStream`

```
FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream("c:/SaveObj3.sav");
DataOutputStream save = new DataOutputStream(saveFile);

save.writeByte(0);

save.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Files class provided by Java 7. It's more easy than expected.

It can be performed in one line:

```
byte[] bytes = new String("message output to be written in file").getBytes();
Files.write(Paths.get("outputpath.txt"), bytes);
```

If you have a File class, you can just replace:

```
Paths.get("outputpath.txt")
```

to:

```
yourOutputFile.toPath()
```

To write only one byte, as you want, you can do the following:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("outputpath.txt"), new byte[1]);

in file properties:
size: 1 bytes
```